# regex to ignore a character in between two string?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

My String is

```
           **abcd
           *[abc]
           <td> **Welcome
               **Welcome Again
           </td>
```

Is their any way in which I can remove the * symbol in between the  tags so that my final string string would be something like

```
            **abcd
             *[abc]
          <td> Welcome
               Welcome Again
           </td>
```

Here all the * between `<td>` and `</td>` are removed
I dont want to use string.

Comment: `string.replace("*", "");`

Comment: [HTML regex alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    if (s.contains("<td>"))
    {
        String first = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("<td>"));
        String last = s.substring(s.indexOf("<td>"), s.indexOf("</td>") + 5);

        System.out.println("result  : "+first + last.replace("**", ""));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("result : "+s);
    }
```